# Karma can't resolve dependency 'kotlin' in kotlin-frontend-plugin

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, kotlin, karma-webpack

I have been trying to get this to work for a day or so now with no luck. Webpack doesn't seem to be injecting the `kotlin` npm module into my tests, even though it is loaded by webpack. So it throws the below error saying it can't find it.

Here's the error log:

```
                          Asset     Size  Chunks         Chunk Names
                           main  1.55 MB       0  [big]  main
classes/java/test/vuekt_test.js  1.37 MB       1  [big]  classes/java/test/vuekt_test.js
chunk    {0} main (main) 1.55 MB [entry]
    [0] ./~/process/browser.js 5.42 kB {0} {1}
    [1] ./~/kotlin/kotlin.js 1.31 MB {0} {1}
    [2] ./js/kitchensink/kotlin/MyComponent.html 2.59 kB {0} {1}
    [3] ./js/kitchensink/kotlin/VueApp.html 725 bytes {0} {1}
    [4] ./~/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js 187 kB {0}
    [5] ./js/vuekt.js 40 kB {0}
    [6] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0}
chunk    {1} classes/java/test/vuekt_test.js (classes/java/test/vuekt_test.js) 1.36 MB [entry]
    [0] ./~/process/browser.js 5.42 kB {0} {1}
    [1] ./~/kotlin/kotlin.js 1.31 MB {0} {1}
    [2] ./js/kitchensink/kotlin/MyComponent.html 2.59 kB {0} {1}
    [3] ./js/kitchensink/kotlin/VueApp.html 725 bytes {0} {1}
    [7] ./classes/java/test/vuekt_test.js 40.6 kB {1} [built]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
30 06 2017 08:36:42.464:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket RaGM1IMTAMuV2JRuAAAA with id 80698172
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Error loading module 'vuekt_test'. Its dependency 'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 'vuekt_test'.
  at classes/java/test/vuekt_test.js:35113
```

As you can see in the log at this line `[1] ./~/kotlin/kotlin.js 1.31 MB {0} {1}`, the kotlin-stdlib-js resource is being loaded by webpack as it should.

It is also included in the `main` bundle that you can see is loaded on this line

```
main  1.55 MB       0  [big]  main
```

However, it is not being injected into `vuekt_test.js`. That's why the error you see above gets thrown.

I don't know how to get it to inject `kotlin` into it though.

Here is my configuration in `build.gradle`:

```
kotlinFrontend {
    npm {
        dependency("vue", "2.3.4")

        devDependency("vue-template-compiler", "2.3.4")
        devDependency("vue-template-es2015-compiler", "1.5.2")
        devDependency("vue-template-loader", "0.3.1") //this requires the above 2 devDependencies

        devDependency("webpack", "2.6.1")
        devDependency("webpack-dev-server", "2.4.4")
        devDependency("css-loader", "0.28.4")
        devDependency("style-loader", "0.18.2")
        devDependency("to-string-loader", "1.1.5")
        devDependency("file-loader", "0.11.2")

        devDependency("karma")
    }

    webpackBundle {
        bundleName = "main"
        contentPath = file('src/web')
        port = 9002
    }

    karma {
        port = 9876
        runnerPort = 9100
        reporters = ["progress"]
        frameworks = ["qunit"]
    }
}
```

And here is the `karma.conf.js` file:

```
var webpackConfig = require("C:\\my_workspace\\vue.kt\\build\\webpack.config.js");
webpackConfig.resolve.modules.push("C:\\my_workspace\\vue.kt\\build\\classes\\java\\test\\vuekt_test.js");

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    "basePath": "C:\\my_workspace\\vue.kt\\build",
    "frameworks": [
        "qunit"
    ],
    "reporters": [
        "progress"
    ],
    "files": [
        "C:\\my_workspace\\vue.kt\\build\\classes\\java\\test\\vuekt_test.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "*~",
        "*.swp",
        "*.swo"
    ],
    "port": 9876,
    "runnerPort": 9100,
    "colors": false,
    "autoWatch": true,
    "browsers": [
        "PhantomJS"
    ],
    "captureTimeout": 5000,
    "singleRun": false,
    "preprocessors": {
        "C:\\my_workspace\\vue.kt\\build\\classes\\java\\test\\vuekt_test.js": [
            "webpack"
        ]
    },
    "plugins": [
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
        "karma-qunit",
        "karma-webpack"
    ],
    "client": {
        "clearContext": false,
        "qunit": {
            "showUI": true,
            "testTimeout": 5000
        }
    },
    "webpack": webpackConfig
})
};
```

What do I need to do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some additional trial and error I found that I needed to declare the type of module that the test should be compiled into.

Adding this to my `build.gradle` file fixed the problem:

```
compileTestKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'commonjs'
}
```